# Are certain tags scaring off viewers?

Tags: discussion, tags, unanswered-questions, views

I have recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108607/jadclipse-not-working-with-eclipse-3-6) on SO about `jadclipse` and noticed a surprisingly low views count.

I noticed that in the **entire repository** of questions there are only 4 questions tagged with `jadclipse` (including mine) and most are not answered and all have a relatively low view count compared to their age.

Can it be that some tags cause people to walk away (even if the question is tagged with other tags that do interest them)?

Comment: They probably don't know anything about `jadclipse`. Why do you expect them to click on your question anyway?

Comment: Maybe it's a relatively obscure topic. I, for one, have no idea what `jadclipse` is.

Comment: @alex: [jadclipse](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/eclipse/decompile-java-classes-automatically-in-eclipse-with-jadclipse-and-jad/). didn't know about it either... @RonK I don't think that tag turns people _away_, it simply does not _attract_ those who don't know jadclipse

Comment: When I first started on Stack Overflow, I spent a lot of time browsing the newest questions.  I learned a lot about other topics besides the ones I knew, and surprisingly, was able to answer questions in many topics I didn't know I had expertise in.  Now, so many questions are posted so fast, that when I go to the next page of newest questions, it's the same page.  15 questions are added as fast as I can read 15 questions, which I suppose is a topic for another meta question.  Now, all I do is look at the newest "tagged" questions.  I don't think I'm the only one in this situation.

Comment: jadclipse scares the hell outta me.  Primarily because of the whole Java thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see many reasons:

1. Not enough knowledge to answer: People who know that do not come on Stack Overflow, and Stack Overflow users don't know it, or there are just a few experts.
2. Too technical: People know it, but they are unwilling to provide answers as it takes too much time to test and formulate answers.
3. Not enough reward: people answer other questions that give them more reputation.

Comment: 4. It doesn't show up on the "Interesting" list of questions based on favourite tags